# Do the Cornets and Crowns of Seasons stay after the event is over?

Tags: runescape

In RuseScape, do the Cornets and Crowns stay after the Crown of Seasons event is over? I do not think I will end up making a full set, so I am hoping the ones I do make stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, in runescape history, I can't think of a single event item that went away because the event ended. I think I still have my frog hat.